# C# simple way to do file I/O with big multidimensional (non-jagged) array of bytes

Tags: c#, arrays, file-io, multidimensional-array

I am working with big multidimensional byte arrays (~500mb per array, like, an array with dimensions of [8,8192,8192]) and I'd like to read and write them into file for storage.

I tried using BinaryFormatter but is very slow (takes minutes to do).

I tried using BinaryWriter but it only takes in a single dimensional array. Now, in C, there was no problem passing multi-dimensional array as single-dimensional. In C#, from what I see, I have two options:

- Allocate another chunk of memory for single-dimensional array, copy data into it with for loops, then write this array into file using BinaryWriter
- Using for loops, write each individual byte into file using BinaryWriter

Obviously it would be much faster if i'd just use byte[] everywhere and instead of using myarray[i,j] use myarray[i+j*myarray_width] but that would require rewrite of whole class just for purpose of easier working of one set of I/O functions (Save/Load).

There's gotta be a better way.

Comment: How bad is it if you went the "using for loops" approach? Is it "good enough"?

Comment: Well, isnt for loop through each array member and individually writing each array member slower than writing whole array at once?

Comment: Probably, but is it fast enough? By which I mean, say the leanest meanest best solution took 30 seconds to run, and loops takes 40 seconds. Would that be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to fast serialization, unsafe code might come in handy. There are two techniques that can help here:

1. Do a memcpy from your `byte[,]` to a fresh `byte[]` that you can pass to `FileStream.Write`. This requires, of course, a temporary doubling of storage space and some copying. You could split this work into 64KB chunks, though.
2. PInvoke to the unmanaged `WriteFile` and pass it the `FileStream.SafeHandle` value. `WriteFile` takes an arbitrary pointer so you can directly write out your `byte[,]` (converted into a `void*`).

Option 2 is maximally fast ("zero-copy").

Sidenote: Unsafe code comes in handy whenever you need to reinterpret bytes. This capability leads to some nice abstractions in C. Fortunately, C# has that capability, too.

Comment: PInvoke seems to be the way to go. Reads 1 gig byte array in 0 seconds (compared to 8 seconds it takes to read manually byte by byte)!

Comment: That is probably with disk caching of course, but still, with same caching reading with for loop takes ~8 seconds

Comment: Yes, byte-by-byte loops generate a lot of instructions that have to be retired at runtime.